# Image upload after submit using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload image using ajax. But i am getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Image in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/request/insert.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: Image in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/request/insert.php on line 9
```

After clicked insert button then i am getting that error. The problem is just image section. Other details will still posting. There's something I missed.But I can not find. Anyone can help me here ?

My ajax code is here:

```
// Insert 
  $("body").on("click",".insert", function(){

     var Desc = $(".Desc").val();
     var Title = $(".Title").val(); 
     var Image = $("#Image").val();

     var dataString = 'Desc=' + Desc +  '&Title=' + Title + '&Image=' + Image ;
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"request/insert.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache:false,
        success: function(html){
          // Do something   
        } 
     });

  });
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="file-field input-field">
      <div class="btn">
         <span>File</span>
         <input type="file" name="Image" id="Image">
      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="textarea1" name="Desc" class="materialize-textarea Desc"></textarea>
          <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input  name="Title" id="first_name2" type="text" class="validate Title">
      <label class="active" for="first_name2">First Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="btn waves-effect waves-light insert" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
include_once 'functions/db.php';
if(isSet($_POST['Title']) && isSet($_POST['Desc']) && isSet($_POST['Image'])) {

    $Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Title']);
    $Desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Desc']);

    $Image = $_FILES['Image']['name'];
    $image_tmp= $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($sliderPath);

    $insert_query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO Post(Title,Desc,Image) VALUES ('$Title','$Desc','$Image')") or die(mysqli_error($db));

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send the image data like the way you are doing now inside jquery , you have to append it inside a `FormData();` and then submit it to your url , as the image is multipart data , replace your javascript code with below:

```
$("body").on("click",".insert", function(){

     var data = new FormData();
     data.append('Desc',$(".Desc").val());
     data.append('Title',$(".Title").val());
     var Image = $("#Image").prop("files")[0];;
    data.append('Image',Image);
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"request/insert.php",
        data: data,
        cache:false,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        success: function(html){
          // Do something   
        } 
     });

  });
```

and inside `php` it is `isset();` not `iSset();` and also inside php change :

```
$_POST['Image']
```

to :

```
$_FILES['Image']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer now it is working fine. I have one question about your answer, how can i delete form values after submit ?

Comment: @DevStud use : `$('#Form').trigger("reset");`  inside success callback it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Your uploaded file information will be available in the global array $_FILES not $_POST and that is why you were not able to access it. You may access the Image information like this

```
$imageName = $_FILES['Image']['name']
```

You should also consider validating user's inputs before saving your data to the database. Rule #1: Never ever trust such data

Answer (score -1):

Try your ajax call like this it will work for sure.

```
$("#Form").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            var dataString  =  new FormData(this);
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"img1.php",
            data: dataString ,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(html){
             console.log(html);
            }, 
            error: function(data){
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
         });
     });
```